# Catenoid like shape changes with pressure difference

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, curvature

I have an object that takes a shape similar to a catenoid, which is known for its zero mean curvature.

According to Laplace's law, the pressure difference is proportional to the mean curvature. This implies that if the mean curvature is zero, then the pressure difference is also zero.

However, I am aware that when  there is a non-zero pressure difference between the inside and outside of the object, which has left me puzzled.

Is it possible to have a shape resembling a catenoid but with a constant pressure difference? Furthermore, how can I relate the curvature to the distance, r(z), from the z-axis to any point z on the boundary of this shape?

Comment: Which is inside and which is outside? Minimal surfaces are always non-compact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Since you are already familiar with $\Delta p=0$ catenary case I shall mention the following extension hints which I trust you can take to the next step.

From equilibrium of static forces which is also the Laplace equation for a soap bubble film / minimal surface. $N$  surface tension property, $H$  mean curvature, we have

$$ \frac{N}{R_1}+  \frac{N}{R_2}= \Delta p $$
$$ \kappa_1+ \kappa_2=  \frac{\Delta p}{N} =2 H $$

A computation and plot yield progressive loops, DeLaunay Unduloids.. depending on the amount of pressure used to blow   or use suction in a cut tube smeared with stearate soapy liquid as shown in various  expanding or contracting bubbles of variable $H =\dfrac{\Delta p}{2N}$ yielding  $CMC$ ( constant mean curvature ) shapes..

To the catenary we add a family of curves, a cylinder, sphere, corrugations, unduloids etc.

Integral of the above ode is

$$ \cos \phi = H r -\frac{C}{r} \tag 1 $$

where $C$ is an arbitrary constant. When $\phi=\pi/2 $ successive  films have a vertical tangent at

$$ r_{vertical ~tgt}= \sqrt{ C/H}, R_2 \to \infty. $$
The soap bubble meridian can be obtained by integration of 1)

*Special cases:*

$$  H=0~ ,\text{Catenary}~;$$
$$ C=0, \text{Sphere} ~;$$
$$  ~2r_{cyl} H =1+\sqrt{1+4CH}~, \text{Cylinder} ;$$

Only a segment of noncompact CMC surfaces can be physically seen between cut tube ends during experimentation if undertaken.

Sorry for the clumsy sketch. Hope you get the idea.

Please consult also if possible the nice book by Cyril Isenberg,  entitled  *Science of Soap Bubbles and Soap Films,* a book I found fascinating on this topic.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's great, thank you, I am checking the book as well and looks great. I've just seen some derivations and illustrations, i think we can write $r=cst cosh(z/cst)$, do you think this will work for both cases, but the constant will depend on the shape and the geoemtry which is a result either of zero or constant difference pressure

Comment: No, that is only  for catenoid types I believe. CMC meridians are found by integrating 1). CMC surfaces ( DeLaunay Unduloids) can be seen in  Wiki reference by Math Wonk below.

Comment: Using the code or otherwise you can find what changes  result in  unduloids ..

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the differential equation for the surface, set the mean curvature H equal to the given pressure difference and apply the axisymmetric formula for  found here: [mean curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_curvature)

The solutions are described here: [constant mean curvature surfaces of revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant-mean-curvature_surface)